# Aws Amplify - Sharing backend of one amplify app with another amplify app

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, backend, aws-amplify

I have two Amplify apps, one has a graphQl back-end and I am not using cognito for auth, I am using API Key instead. I would like to be able to share the back-end of app 1 with app 2.

Now when i developing in my local-machine, I have copied the aws-exports.js information from app 1 (Where I initialized the back-end) into app 2 and it all works perfectly, but when I deploy my app 2 into Amplify, I get a **No Credentials** error.

I followed the instruction in this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/reuse-backends.html

Still nothing.

Second thing I did was instead of importing the aws-exports I entered the config object directly when initializing Amplify. And not I get this error:

```
net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

 
Error: Network Error at e.exports (https://dev.d2hvg386uur67i.amplifyapp.com/static/js/main.0ca38d8c.js:2:143424) at v.onerror (https://dev.d2hvg386uur67i.amplifyapp.com/static/js/main.0ca38d8c.js:2:138421)
```

I don't know where to go from here, or what steps I have missed.

Any help would be extremely appreciated

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out...

Follow the instructions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/reuse-backends.html and make sure you **Uncheck** the **Enable full-stack continuous deployments (CI/CD)**. This will stop app 2 from rebuilding the back-end of app 1.

Then on app's 2 index.js or app.js, wherever you are initiating your Amplify.

Copy the aws-exports object and past it directly on your index/app.js, insted of importing it from the aws-exports.

```
//Initialize Amplify
Amplify.configure({
  "aws_project_region": "us-east-2",
    "aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint": "https://***************************.appsync-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
    "aws_appsync_region": "us-east-2",
    "aws_appsync_authenticationType": "API_KEY",
    "aws_appsync_apiKey": "a32-**************************"
});
```

The reason for this is that the aws-exports file gets generated at build time when you deploy to amplify, so it will overwrite the config from the other app.

It is wierd that even when connecting the two it still does not generate the right file.

And this is now working for me.